# Server and client click not working together

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My Button1_click is server sided code that when the button is pushed, data is submitted into a database. My SubmitForm() is clientside code. How can I get both to work when I push the button called button1? (my submit button). The code below only fires the Onclick when the button is pushed and the OnClientClick doesn't.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Onclick = "Button1_Click" 
            OnClientClick = "javascript:SubmitForm();return false" 
            Text="Submit" Width="98px"
              />
```

This is my submit form code

```
function SubmitForm() {


    if (document.getElementById("hawbtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HAWB (B/L)!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("invrefpotxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the INV/REF/PO!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("hppartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HP PART NUM!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("iecpartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the IEC PART NUM!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("qtytxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the QUANTITY!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("bulkstxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BULKS!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("boxplttxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BOX/PLT!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("rcvddatetxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the DATE!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("statustxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the STATUS!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("carriertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the CARRIER!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("shippertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the SHIPPER!");
        return false;

    }

//create coo_bto_test.bat
    var sText, s;
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    alert("called");
    if (!fso.FileExists("C:\\COO_BTO_Test.bat")) {
        s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\COO_BTO_Test.bat", true);
        sText = "@echo off";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":Lbl";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XA^MD0^PRB^JVY^LL1760^LH%XL%,%YL%^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,08^BY2,2.0,32^BCN,N,N,N^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,48^AF,8,8^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":END";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^PQ1     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XZ     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM MODE COM1 9600"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM TYPE COO.TXT > COM1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "TYPE COO.TXT > LPT1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);
    }
      }

     function WriteToFile(sText) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\PRT_Test.bat", true);
        s.WriteLine(sText);
        s.Close();
    }
```

and this is my button1_click code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into John_IEP_Crossing_Dock_Shipment values('" + generateidtxt.Text + "','" + hawbtxt.Text + "','" + invrefpotxt.Text + "','" + hppartnumtxt.Text + "','" + iecpartnumtxt.Text + "','" + qtytxt.Text + "','" + bulkstxt.Text + "','" + boxplttxt.Text + "','" + rcvddatetxt.Text + "','" + statustxt.Text + "','" + carriertxt.Text + "','" + shippertxt.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        generateidtxt.Text = "";
        hawbtxt.Text = "";
        invrefpotxt.Text = "";
        hppartnumtxt.Text = "";
        iecpartnumtxt.Text = "";
        qtytxt.Text = "";
        bulkstxt.Text = "";
        boxplttxt.Text = "";
        rcvddatetxt.Text = "";
        statustxt.Text = "";
        carriertxt.Text = "";
        shippertxt.Text = "";
        con.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Is your button disabled when the page is rendered? If so, the OnClientClick will NOT be written to the HTML

Comment: Nope, I believe it is not disabled when the page is rendered.

Comment: @user2457203 can you update the question with `SubmitForm` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Onclick = "Button1_Click" 
            OnClientClick = "javascript:SubmitForm();" 
            Text="Submit" Width="98px"
/>
```

**EDIT:**

```
function SubmitForm() {


    if (document.getElementById("hawbtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HAWB (B/L)!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("invrefpotxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the INV/REF/PO!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("hppartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the HP PART NUM!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("iecpartnumtxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the IEC PART NUM!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("qtytxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the QUANTITY!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("bulkstxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BULKS!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("boxplttxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the BOX/PLT!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("rcvddatetxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the DATE!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("statustxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the STATUS!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("carriertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the CARRIER!");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("shippertxt").value == "") {
        alert("Please enter the SHIPPER!");
        return false;

    }

//create coo_bto_test.bat
    var sText, s;
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    alert("called");
    if (!fso.FileExists("C:\\COO_BTO_Test.bat")) {
        s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\COO_BTO_Test.bat", true);
        sText = "@echo off";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":Lbl";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XA^MD0^PRB^JVY^LL1760^LH%XL%,%YL%^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,08^BY2,2.0,32^BCN,N,N,N^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS   \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^FO66,48^AF,8,8^SN%Sno0%,1,Y^FS     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = ":END";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^PQ1     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "ECHO \"^XZ     \">> COO.TXT";
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM MODE COM1 9600"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "REM TYPE COO.TXT > COM1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);

        sText = "TYPE COO.TXT > LPT1"
        s.WriteLine(sText);
    }
        return true;
      }
```

Comment: Please share the `SubmitForm` function.. Check whether you are returning `false` anywhere in this function..

Comment: okay I posted the SubmitForm function.. I can see I have return false on there.. I tried removing the false part of return. But the same thing happens as well.

Comment: So, I guess when you are saying this is not working.. it is actually going into any of these `return false;` Please check the unit testing scenario.. or please use `return true;` at the end of `SubmitForm` function.

Comment: I changed all the return false; to return; in all the alerts, and I have removed return false from the asp button. When I push the button, I left the first textbox blank so that it displays the first alert. after it's done alerting it still runs the onclick..

Comment: that's what it should. Do not change it everywhere. Either you use such a test case so that it do not go into that `if` blocks OR you use `return true;` at the end of the function.

Comment: while testing please fill in all the textboxes and then click on the button.

Comment: I'm alittle confused.. could you show me what my SubmitForm() should look like?

Comment: Hmm.. that's what it was originally before but it didn't work either.. anyways I think I figured out the problem.. I put this as the onclientclick... OnClientClick = "javascript: return SubmitForm(); and now everything seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**remove** *return false* from `OnClientClick`

```
OnClientClick = "javascript:SubmitForm()"
```

since you return false from client click, server event will not fire

if you return boolean value from sumitform you can do as below

```
OnClientClick="javascript: return SubmitForm();"
```

if you return `true` from `SubmitForm` method then server event also fires.

### Update

you only return false from your `SubmitForm` method, at the end if all required inputs are there in the form you can return true

Comment: Could you show the proper code of how it should look like, so I can copy and paste it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return false` from your javascript function. you will get it working.

**FYI:**

with `return false` form will not be submitted:

And **Returning false** from a JavaScript event usually cancels the "default" behavior - in the case of links, it tells the browser to not follow the link.